# Run shell script using Spark cluster mode in the node where the spark submit is issued

Tags: java, scala, shell, apache-spark, unix

I have a Unix shell script that creates some files based on business logic. I have another project which is java spark based and we run it in cluster mode. By any chance can we call the shell script successfully without making any code changes in the shell script. Currently, it only works when I run the job in client mode.

Comment: Where are your different elements? Scripts? Cluster? Data? Remember: all needs to be accessible from everywhere.